# QWebKit how running js on page from python

Tags: python, pyqt5, qwebkit

How can I inject JavaScript into a page via QWebKit?

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWebKitWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication

js = "alert('test');"

def function():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    web = QWebView()
    web.load(QUrl("url"))

    # run js

    web.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    function()
```

The js code is a simple example, I don't know exactly what code will be run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to run through the evaluateJavaScript() method of the mainFrame of the page associated with the view. It is advisable to run it after loading the page:

```py
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt5.QtWebKitWidgets import QWebView
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication

js = "alert('test');"


def function():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    web = QWebView()
    web.load(QUrl("https://stackoverflow.com"))
    # web.page().mainFrame().evaluateJavaScript(js)

    def on_load_finished(ok):
        if ok:
            web.page().mainFrame().evaluateJavaScript(js)

    web.loadFinished.connect(on_load_finished)

    web.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    function()
```